# Adding a listener to a button created by .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, event-handling, html-lists, innerhtml, addeventlistener

I am trying to add a listener to a button created by .innerHTML after receiving a listener. This is the code:

```
let inputConfirm = document.getElementById('inputConfirm');
let inputText = document.getElementById('inputText');
let displayList = document.getElementById('displayList');

inputConfirm.addEventListener('click', e=>listElement())
const listElement = () => {

    let inputValue = inputText.value //takes input from textbox
    let newValue = "<li class='each-item'><div class='listbox'>" + inputValue + "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'><button class='delete-button'>X</button></div></li>"; //EACH list element that I want to add to the ordered list.
    if(inputValue !== ""){
        displayList.innerHTML += newValue;
        inputText.value = "";//clears the text box
    };
};
```

I need the button with class "delete-button" created via newValue variable to be clickable and send a console.log

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried? Take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you want to output in the console but the simple way is to add onclick event into .innerHTML and add a function.

```
let inputConfirm = document.getElementById('inputConfirm');
let inputText = document.getElementById('inputText');
let displayList = document.getElementById('displayList');

inputConfirm.addEventListener('click', e=>listElement())
const listElement = () => {

    let inputValue = inputText.value //takes input from textbox
    let newValue = "<li class='each-item'><div class='listbox'>" + inputValue + "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'><button class='delete-button' onclick='toConsole(event)'>X</button></div></li>"; //EACH list element that I want to add to the ordered list.
    if(inputValue !== ""){
        displayList.innerHTML += newValue;
        inputText.value = "";//clears the text box
    };
};

function toConsole(e){
    console.log(e.target);
}
```